# Best way to create Combination of records (Order does not matter, no repetition allowed) in mySQL tables

Tags: mysql, permutation, combinations

I hope I don't butcher the explanation of my question:

I've got a table that has hundreds of rows, each row is a recipe with nutritional information, for example:

recipe_table:

```
id  | calories | protein| carbs | fat

recipe1, 100,    20g,     10g,     2g
recipe2, 110,    10g,     12g,     12g
recipe3, 240,    20g,     1g,      23g
....
```

I needed to create a new table (recipe_index) that would show every possible combination of every recipe in recipe_table as a set of 3, so it would look something like:

recipe_index:

```
id1     | id2    | id3    |calories| protein | carbs | fat
recipe1, recipe2, recipe3,   450,     50g,      23g,   37g
....
```

Basically it allows me to query recipe_index and say "what 3 recipe combinations come to a total value that's between 440 calories and 460 calories"

My current code for doing this works at 3 meals, however I end up with about 450,000 records in recipe_index, I need to do this same thing for 4,5 and 6 meals as well, so I'm calculating millions and millions of records at the end of this. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Perhaps I need to look into partitioning a table for each range?

My current SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO recipe_index
SELECT distinct '3' as nummeals, t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3, 0 as id4,   
t1.calories_ps+t2.calories_ps+t3.calories_ps as calories, t1.protein_ps+t2.protein_ps+t3.protein_ps as  
protein, t1.carbohydrate_ps+t2.carbohydrate_ps+t3.carbohydrate_ps as carbohydrate, 
t1.fat_ps+t2.fat_ps+t3.fat_ps as fat from recipes t1 inner join  recipes t2  on t1.Id < t2.Id inner join  recipes t3  on t2.Id < t3.Id WHERE t1.image <> '' AND t2.image <> '' AND t3.image <> ''
```

If I missed anything obvious please let me know

Comment: I can't resist:  http://xkcd.com/287/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with a join.  In order to prevent duplicates, you want a condition where the recipe ids are in order (this also prevents one recipe from appearing three times):

```
select r1.id, r2.id, r3.id,
       (r1.calories + r2.calories + r3.calories) as calories,
       (r1.protein + r2.protein + r3.protein) as protein,
       (r1.carbs + r2.carbs + r3.carbs) as carbs,
       (r1.fat + r2.fat + r3.fat) as calories
from recipe_table r1 join
     recipe_table r2
     where r1.id < r2.id join
     recipe_table r3
     where r2.id < r3.id;
```

The only difference from your query is that the `distinct` is not necessary, because the ordering prevents duplicates.

The problem you are facing is that there are a lot of combinations.  So there are millions of combinations of 4 recipes.  I'm guessing you are starting with 77 or so recipes. The number of combinations of 4 of them is 77*76*75*74 -- and this sequence will grow quickly for 5 and 6 combos.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Sorry for the late reply, had some other issues I had to tend to.

Yeah, I'm definitely going to have millions of records (I've got 450 recipes in the recipes table lol).

I want to do this though, so I'm curious the best way of going about it, I'm going to give yours a try, thanks for pointing out that I can get rid of the distinct.

Any suggestions on if I should look into partitioning a table, or perhaps completely separate tables all together (ie. 100-200calories, 201-400calories etc..)?

Comment: @Neostim . . . How many distinct counts do you have in each column?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, what do you mean distinct counts in each column?

Comment: @Neostim . . . Yes.  You might be able to group the recipes based on these factors, and reduce the number of combinations.

Comment: Just an update, I did run your version of the code and it completed in 200 seconds with 17.8 million records, MUCH faster then mine which wouldn't even complete :)

In the recipes table, there are 457 unique records for calories, 447 for protein,  457 for carbs, 429 for fat... seeing as there are 467 total recipes in the table I'm guessing this wont help me?

Based on my math, if I want to do 4 meals using this method, it will come out to 2.1 billion records.. which obviously isn't going to work out too well for me :(

P.S. thanks again for helping me with this.

Comment: @Neostim . . . I'm glad it helped (and I'm surprised by the increase in performance).  The only thing I can think of is some sort of grouping them into ranges and then determine which combinations of groups meet the conditions first.  This would reduce the computational complexity.  That, or quantum computing (it's supposed to be good at this sort of problem ;-).

Comment: Hmm, so last question, with the grouping, say in the 18 million record table, there's 200k unique records of the "calories" column, is there some way in mySQL that allows you to group and point to another table/partition/something else if what they're looking for falls within that range? If not, I guess I'll try creating 50 partitions or so of calorie ranges and give that a try.
Thanks again!!