# Create fixed length non-repeating permutation within certain ranges in PHP

Tags: php, permutation

I've got a table with 1000 recipes in it, each recipe has calories, protein, carbs and fat values associated with it.

I need to figure out an algorithm in PHP that will allow me to specify value ranges for calories, protein, carbs and fat as well as dictating the number of recipes in each permutation. Something like:

```
getPermutations($recipes, $lowCal, $highCal, $lowProt, $highProt, $lowCarb, $highCarb, $lowFat, $highFat, $countRecipes)
```

The end goal is allowing a user to input their calorie/protein/carb/fat goals for the day (as a range, 1500-1600 calories for example), as well as how many meals they would like to eat (count of recipes in each set) and returning all the different meal combinations that fit their goals.

I've tried this previously by populating a table with every possible combination (see: [Best way to create Combination of records (Order does not matter, no repetition allowed) in mySQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843598/best-way-to-create-combination-of-records-order-does-not-matter-no-repetition) ) and querying it with the range limits, however that proved not to be efficient as I end up with billions of records to scan through and it takes an indefinite amount of time.

I've found some permutation algorithms that are close to what I need, but don't have the value range restraint for calories/protein/carbs/fat that I'm looking for (see: [Create fixed length non-repeating permutation of larger set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175257/create-fixed-length-non-repeating-permutation-of-larger-set)) I'm at a loss at this point when it comes to this type of logic/math, so any help is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: If you are doing one query per request, can't BETWEEN() do the job for you?

Comment: I've edited to add the $recipes variable above btw. I'm not sure what you mean with between(), are you referring to my older mySQL post?

Comment: The first step in any seemingly very hard problem is ask if you really want what you are asking for. Specifically, do you *really* want *all* meal combinations that fit their goal? Depending on what values are put in, this could range from 0 to Billions, and what reasonably is a person to do with billions? If you reconstruct what you want, for instance 5 suggested menus that fit but a person can ask for 5 more, etc, then that is vastly easier to do! In this case you can just iteratively select random meals that fit the standard, and present them as a set. 1-10 small queries is painless.

Comment: This approach would also allow you to take 10 meal suggestions, allow a person to select some they want or don't want, and then regenerate suggestions that include those meals plus random others. Then a person could iterate until they have meal plans to their satisfaction, rather than having to page through endless recipe/plans or start from scratch with each random pull from the database, etc. Obviously this depends upon your use-case, but if you really need to deal with Very Big Data it's just going to be slow and unwieldy 'because'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some comment clarification, I can suggest one way to go about it. Specifically, this is my "try the simplest thing that could possibly work" approach to a problem that is potentially quite tricky.

First, the tricky part is that the sum of all meals has to be in a certain range, but SQL does not have a built-in feature that I'm aware of that does specifically what you want in one pass; that's ok, though, as we can just implement this functionality in PHP instead.

So lets say you request 5 meals that will total 2000 calories - we leave the other variables aside for simplicity, but they will work the same way. We then calculate that the 'average' meal is 2000/5=400 calories, but obviously any one meal could be over or under that amount. I'm no dietician, but I assume you'll want no meal that takes up more than 1.25x-2x the average meal size, so we can restrict out initial query to this amount.

```
$maxCalPerMeal = ($highCal / $countRecipes) * 1.5;
$mealPlanCaloriesRemaining = $highCal; # more on this one in a minute
```

We then request 1 random meal which is less than `$maxCalPerMeal`, and 'save' it as our first meal. We then subtract its actual calorie count from `$mealPlanCaloriesRemaining`. We now recalculate:

```
$maxCalPerMeal = ($highCal / $countRecipesRemaining) * 1.5); # 1.5 being a maximum deviation from average multiple
```

Now the next query will ask for both a random meal that is less than `$maxCalPerMeal` AND `$mealPlanCaloriesRemaining`, AND NOT one of the meals you already have saved in this particular meal plan option (thus ensuring unique meals - no mac'n'cheese for breakfast, lunch, and dinner!). And we update the variables as in the last query, until you reach the end. For the last meal requested it we don't care about the average and it's associated multiple, as thanks to a compound query you'll get what you want anyway and don't need to complicate your control loops.

Assuming the worst case with the 5 meal 2000 calorie max diet:

Meal 1: 600 calories
Meal 2: 437 
Meal 3: 381
Meal 4: 301
Meal 5: 281

Or something like that, and in most cases you'll get something a bit nicer and more random. But in the worst-case it still works! Now this actually just plain works for the usual case. Adding more maximums like for fat and protein, etc, is easy, so lets deal with the lows next.

All we need to do to support "minimum calories per day" is add another set of averages, as such:

```
$minCalPerMeal = ($lowCal / $countRecipes) * .5 # this time our multiplier is less than one, as we allow for meals to be bigger than average we must allow them to be smaller as well
```

And you restrict the query to being greater than this calculated minimum, recalculating with each loop, and happiness naturally ensues.

Finally we must deal with the degenerate case - what if using this method you end up needing a meal that is to small or too big to fill the last slot? Well, you can handle this a number of ways. Here's what I'd recommended.

The easiest is just returning less than the desired amount of meals, but this might be unacceptable. You could also have special low calorie meals that, due to the minimum average dietary content, would only be likely to be returned if someone really had to squeeze in a light meal to make the plan work. I rather like this solution.

The second easiest is throw out the meal plan you have so far and regenerate from scratch; it might work this time, or it just might not, so you'll need a control loop to make sure you don't get into an infinite work-intensive loop.

The least easy, requires a control loop max iteration again, but here you use a specific strategy to try to get a more acceptable meal plan. In this you take the optional meal with the highest value that is exceeding your dietary limits and throw it out, then try pulling a smaller meal - perhaps one that is no greater than the new calculated average. It might make the plan as a whole work, or you might go over value on another plan, forcing you back into a loop that could be unresolvable - or it might just take a few dozen iterations to get one that works.

Though this sounds like a lot when writing it out, even a very slow computer should be able to churn out hundreds of thousands of suggested meal plans every few seconds without pausing. Your database will be under very little strain even if you have millions of recipes to choose from, and the meal plans you return will be as random as it gets. It would also be easy to make certain multiple suggested meal plans are not duplicates with a simple comparison and another call or two for an extra meal plan to be generated - without fear of noticeable delay!

By breaking things down to small steps with minimal mathematical overhead a daunting task becomes manageable - and you don't even need a degree in mathematics to figure it out :)

(As an aside, I think you have a very nice website built there, so no worries!)

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I wanted to comment here to let you know I haven't abandoned this, my VPS went down about 5 hours ago and I'm still trying to get a reply from my provider about it, once we're back up I'm going to look at this more.

Comment: This will suit my requirements perfectly, thanks for taking the time to go into the detail in explaining it!

Comment: Ok, I'm completely stuck and pulling my hair out at something that should be simple but I'm missing something, I've created this logic in PHP, except the minimum calories part, I must be thinking of it wrong, if I say max calories is 2000 my logic works fine, the calories are always under 2000 calories, but as soon as I try to add in min calories, the logic will work in that overall it will try to make sure it totals more then the min, but on a meal by meal basis the min is often higher then the max calories.

Could you expand on how you see the Minimum Calories logic working?

Comment: I think I figured out a way, calculating the percentage between the total low calorie and high calorie for the entire meal plan, then using that percentage to calculate the low calorie per meal off of the high calorie limit.